Problem with drawing a commutative diagram
I am an experienced LaTeX user, and I have drawn many diagrams in my life. My trouble right now is (I will put up a full example)
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_1} \arrow{d}{\beta_1} & 2 \arrow{r}{\alpha_2} \arrow{d}{\beta_2} & 3 \arrow{r}{\alpha_3} \arrow{d}{\beta_3} & .... \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-2}} \arrow{d} & n-1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-1}} \arrow{d}{\beta_{n-1}} & n \arrow{d}{\beta_n}\\

1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_1} \arrow{d}{\beta_1} & 2 \arrow{r}{\alpha_2} \arrow{d}{\beta_2} & 3 \arrow{r}{\alpha_3} \arrow{d}{\beta_3} & .... \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-2}} \arrow{d} & n-1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-1}} \arrow{d}{\beta_{n-1}} & n \arrow{d}{\beta_n}\\

\end{tikzcd}\]\\

\end{document}

and he (the compiler, that at the bottom of the page which appears once you hit Texify or hit control-shift-P) says:

! Package pgf Error : No shape named 'tikz@f@28-3-1' is known.
See the pgf package documentation for explanation.
Type H  for immediate help

.....
I think the culprit is a tikzcd arrow in cell 2-1.
\errmessage ...currentrow -tikzcd@currentcolumn }

\end{tikzcd}

any help? Sowwy not a programmer, a mathematician who loves video games (but video games do not love him back). Thankieees!

Welcome to TeX.SX! You use \arrow{d} in the second row which represents an arrow pointing down, but you don't define a third row. Apart from that, remove empty lines inside the tikzcd environment and delete the \\  outside the math-mode block.

You use \arrow{d} in the second row, which is supposed to draw arrows pointing down, but you don't define a third row, so there are no cells to point to. Just add this row.
Note that you should not put blank lines inside a tikzcd environment. Also, I'd remove the last \\ outside the math-mode and change the dots to \cdots.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[\begin{tikzcd}
1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_1} \arrow{d}{\beta_1} & 2 \arrow{r}{\alpha_2} \arrow{d}{\beta_2} & 
    3 \arrow{r}{\alpha_3} \arrow{d}{\beta_3} & \cdots \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-2}} \arrow{d} & 
    n-1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-1}} \arrow{d}{\beta_{n-1}} & n \arrow{d}{\beta_n} \\
1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_1} \arrow{d}{\beta_1} & 2 \arrow{r}{\alpha_2} \arrow{d}{\beta_2} & 
    3 \arrow{r}{\alpha_3} \arrow{d}{\beta_3} & \cdots \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-2}} \arrow{d} & 
    n-1 \arrow{r}{\alpha_{n-1}} \arrow{d}{\beta_{n-1}} & n \arrow{d}{\beta_n} \\
{} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\
\end{tikzcd}\]

\end{document}



Just for comparison using xy package: the syntax for simple diagrams is very near to that tikz-cd.
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[cmtip,all]{xy}
\begin{document}
\[
\xymatrix{
1 \ar[r]^{\alpha_1} \ar[d]^{\beta_1} & 2 \ar[r]^{\alpha_2} \ar[d]^{\beta_2} & 
    3 \ar[r]^{\alpha_3} \ar[d]^{\beta_3} & \cdots \ar[r]^{\alpha_{n-2}} & 
    n-1 \ar[r]^{\alpha_{n-1}} \ar[d]^{\beta_{n-1}} & n \ar[d]^{\beta_n} \\
1 \ar[r]^{\alpha_1} \ar[d]^{\beta_1} & 2 \ar[r]^{\alpha_2} \ar[d]^{\beta_2} & 
    3 \ar[r]^{\alpha_3} \ar[d]^{\beta_3} & \cdots \ar[r]^{\alpha_{n-2}} & 
    n-1 \ar[r]^{\alpha_{n-1}} \ar[d]^{\beta_{n-1}} & n \ar[d]^{\beta_n} \\
{} & {} & {} & {} & {} & {} \\
}
\]
\end{document}


